# How to run php script from android's browser?

Tags: php, android, xampp

Can some tell me how to run how to run the my php file from android mobile. I can run my php file from the PC via `localhost:8081/abc/index.php` . But i can not use this from mobile browser. i'am already connected to wifi network via phone.

Comment: PHP executes server-side, on the webserver. Your Android phone has a web browser, not a web server.

Comment: i know it. u can use so many web site from ur mobile browser. Then ur browser is web server? try to understand my question. @JonathonReinhart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the IP address of your PC, then use that in place of `localhost`. `localhost` refers to accessing the device currently being used.

So, if your PC's IP address was `192.168.0.2`, you would use `192.168.0.2:8081/abc/index.php` from your Android device.

To find your PC's IP address, follow these instructions for your relevant OS:

- **Windows**: Press windows key+r, type `cmd` in the box that appears. Type `ipconfig` into the command prompt window. The IP address you need will be under your network adapter as the `IPv4 Address`.
- **Mac**: Open System Preferences, go to Network. Select your network adapter, and your IP address will be shown directly underneath your connection status.
- **Linux**: Open terminal, type `ifconfig`. Your IP address will be shown under your network adapter as the `inet addr`.

Comment: PC's IP address means wifi connection's ip address ?

Comment: Yes. I just added instructions to find your IP address, follow them.

Comment: i used that but it doesn't work ... :(

Comment: It'd be great to know what's going wrong, exactly, otherwise how can I help? It's probably something to do with your network configuration.

Comment: i create my wifihostspot using these keywords in cmd. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=networkname key=networkpassword
netsh wlan start hostednetwork` that is what i did to config network connection

Comment: i used ping command with my pc's ip address like this `192.168.137.1` it is worked. But using port `192.168.137.1:8081` it doesn't work

Comment: Check your server's configuration, development configurations often aren't set up to be accessible from outside the server itself.

Comment: How can i check that ?

Comment: Read the configuration tutorials for your server ([here's the apache tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/tutorials.html)). You need to know the very basics of web development.